# How far is it possible to develop cardinals without ordinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm wondering which of the usual facts about cardinals in ZFC can be established without using ordinal arithmetic at all. After all the definitions of a cardinal (as a class of equivalence), and also of limit/successor/regular/singular cardinals etc. do not involve order types. Is it possible to develop "just" cardinals, without working with ordinals? Is there an analogue of transfinite recursion that "just" uses cardinals? Does there exist a treatment of cardinals written up along these lines?

Comment: I only mark this interesting because I cannot understand the difference between ordinal numbers and cardinal numbers based on wikipedia's explanation: [Ordinals are an extension of the natural numbers different from integers and from cardinals.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).  I always assumed that the cardinal numbers _were_ the natural numbers and thus an extension of them would _also_ be cardinal (natural) numbers.  I mean even if my sequence was $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...$  each value could be mapped to a natural (counting) number.

Comment: ...and if you object that the Fibonacci sequence does _not_ provide a unique _next_ value or a unique _current_ value then I can simply change my sequence to $1_a, 1_b, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...$.  Now you can uniquely determine the next value based on the value of $1$ (i.e. whether it's $1_a$ or $1_b$)..

Comment: @Jared, when you think to ordinal numbers you are thinking to well-ordered sets, that is, the ordinal represented by $\mathbb N$ is not the same as $\mathbb N\cup\{+\infty\}$ (the second set has a maximum, the first one does not, so they are not the same as ordered sets). Even if this two posets represent different ordinals they clearly have the same cardinality so they represent the same cardinal number. Of course, for finite sets, both ordinals and cardinal can be represented by natural numbers so the two notions a fortiori coincide for finite sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, how far is a bit difficult to answer. Because one can rarely know if what they know on the topic is "as far as it can get".

But you can develop some of the basic theory. All the cardinal arithmetic is doable. You can even prove that $a^2=a$ using Zorn's lemma without appealing directly to ordinals. And this will allow you to even develop basic cardinal exponentiation consequences in $\sf ZFC$.

You can even develop the notion of cofinality can be defined even without ordinals, but using partitions and cardinals instead, and talk about Koenig's theorem.

But I don't think that you can get truly far. You can still define what is a successor cardinal, and what are limit cardinals, but without the ordinals to index them, you're missing quite a bit. The deep structure of the cardinals (which is the little they have left after the axiom of choice trivializes the arithmetic basics and nothing substantial can be proved about exponentiation besides Koenig's theorem).

So the question is, how far are you trying to get? If you want something which is in the confines of a basic course in elementary set theory, sure you can do all that without talking about ordinals, but you're missing out. Because ordinal make the structure of the cardinals, and you'll be touching the trunk of an elephant instead of taking ten steps back and admiring the beast.

And as for written references. I know of none, because set theory books usually aim to teach ordinals as well. For what it's worth, if you're willing to pick and choose, you can find proofs for all of the above on this very site.

Comment: "The deep structure of the cardinals" is left as a fragment, and just as I was getting interested...

Comment: @user18921: I think it's impossible to understand PCF without any knowledge of ordinals, and I think that this is what I meant when I wrote about deep structure. There's other things as well, which are not PCF and can be called deep, but those too often utilize ordinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not sure if you will find this amusing, but my question this morning is really a duplicate of this, but asking the answerers to follow a prescribed (to me natural) path. And I never mentioned ordinals! Sorry, but as you can tell, I can get animated.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt: As long as you not [re-animated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Animator), that's fine. As for the duplicate, admittedly, I've posted so many answers that I don't remember all of them.